# FineUploader with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fine-uploader

I am working on a project using Laravel 3. I need to have users be able to upload images to my server. I have gotten it to work using the standard Laravel Input and File classes but I want to link that to FineUploader (http://fineuploader.com/) so I have a better front-end interface. I have gotten this to work fine with straight PHP but I don't know how to do it using Laravel. Does anyone know how I can implement this or possibly another front end visual uploader in Laravel?

I want the user to be able to see the upload progress and whether it completes successfully or not.

Comment: What, specifically, are you struggling with?  Client-side?  Server-side?  What have you tried, and what specific issues have you run into?

Comment: I tried using the same PHP uploader that I used on a normal PHP site. I put tried to put the PHP uploader file in both the application/libraries folder and /public/js folder and neither seemed to work. I kept getting errors saying:
[22:43:10.749] [FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs...
[22:43:10.751] [FineUploader] Sending upload request for 0
[22:43:10.886] [FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 0
[22:43:10.886] [FineUploader] responseText = {"error":" or executable.","uploadName":null}

Comment: Instead of using the PHP custom PHP connector though, I would like to somehow link the front end of the uploader to the Input and File functions built into the server end of Laravel.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Laravel.  I'll have to take a look and get back to you in about 12 hours.

Comment: It seems like most of your questions should be answered in the Laravel requests documentation.  This isn't really a Fine Uploader question, unless I'm missing something.  Fine Uploader will send a multipart-encoded POST request for each file, which you will need to handle server-side.

Comment: You're not missing anything Ray, you're absolutely correct. All Sean needs to do is build an interface for the library to interact with Laravels Response and Input class'.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Instead of having the PHP connector as it's own file, I moved that code to a method in a controller. I set the FineUploader endpoint to that URI and also moved the qqFileUploader class to the libraries.

Comment: My uploader is currently only part of a form, is there a way to make it so the upload doesn't occur until the form submit button is pressed? I want to avoid someone uploading a photo and not completing the rest of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, please see Laravel's requests documentation for more information on handling the MPE POST requests that Fine Uploader sends.

As for your latest question, you can set Fine Uploader into "manual upload mode", when selected files are only uploaded when you call a specific API method.  On form submittal, you can call this API method.  There is a [non-jQuery example](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-demo.html#demo1) and a [jQuery example](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-with-jquery-wrapper-demo.html#demo1) that demonstrates this on the [home page](http://fineuploader.com).  Please also see the [options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html) and [API](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/fineuploaderbasic.html) documentation.

Comment: I think I have most everything figured out. I can use params to submit the rest of the form. My only other question, which I don't think is possible with how fine-uploader works, but is it possible to submit the files without using Ajax?

After submitting my form, I want it to validate everything and then return errors if something is wrong. I could just leave it as is and return the errors with JSON, but I would rather just reload the page with the errors from PHP.

Comment: One option is client-side validation of your form fields.  I realize that this is not 100% safe as a malicious user can defeat this type of validation.  Another option is to submit your user-supplied values/form-fields via ajax and not reload the page.  A third option is to disconnect the files from the rest of the form.  Perhaps you could create a wizard where step 1 requires the user fills out a form, and step two (the next page) involves uploading files.

Comment: I'd also be interested to hear your thoughts on a [similar request made by another user](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/781).  Please add any comments you might have to the associated Github issue.